# Unable to Mount External USB SSD

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I bought a 1TB external USB SSD (Shadow). I want to copy files from an old disk and use it with Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 7 (so NTFS). But it won't automount. The internal drive is SSD as well and works fine.

Output from `fdisk -l`:

```
Failed to read extended partition table (offset=534194174): Invalid argument
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x31ac2baa

Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *           63      48194     48132  23.5M  6 FAT16
/dev/sdb2           48195   49833629  49785435  23.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3        49833630  534192238 484358609   231G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       534194174 1000130559 465936386 222.2G  5 Extended

Disk /dev/sdc: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/isw_cidiagjcei_Volume1: 476.9 GiB, 512067108864 bytes, 1000131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x31ac2baa

Device                               Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/isw_cidiagjcei_Volume1p1 *           63      48194     48132  23.5M  6 FAT16
/dev/mapper/isw_cidiagjcei_Volume1p2          48195   49833629  49785435  23.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/mapper/isw_cidiagjcei_Volume1p3       49833630  534192238 484358609   231G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/mapper/isw_cidiagjcei_Volume1p4      534194174 1000130559 465936386 222.2G  5 Extended
/dev/mapper/isw_cidiagjcei_Volume1p5      534194176  966676479 432482304 206.2G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_cidiagjcei_Volume1p6      966678528 1000130559  33452032    16G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

and `dmesg`:

```
[ 755.437821] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdg] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  755.557421] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdg] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  755.817476] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  755.834204] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
[  755.834207] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  755.834209] usb 2-2: Product: Shadow
[  755.834210] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: U32
[  755.834211] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 20140324001449
[  755.835387] scsi host18: uas
[  755.835746] scsi 18:0:0:0: Direct-Access     U32      Shadow           0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  755.836170] sd 18:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[  755.837166] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] 2000409264 512-byte logical blocks: (1.02 TB/953 GiB)
[  755.837477] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Write Protect is off
[  755.837479] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  755.837636] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  755.839341]  sdg: [CUMANA/ADFS] sdg1 [ADFS] sdg1
[  755.839343] sdg: partition table partially beyond EOD, enabling native capacity
[  755.840168]  sdg: [CUMANA/ADFS] sdg1 [ADFS] sdg1
[  755.840170] sdg: partition table partially beyond EOD, truncated
[  755.840173] sdg: p1 size 4067027304 extends beyond EOD, truncated
[  755.841014] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk
[  757.804615] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 13
[  757.805846] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  757.924591] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

and `Thunar`:

```
mckelvey@mckelvey-XPS-8700:~$ thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "usb".
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "uas".
thunar-volman: Unknown block device type "disk".
thunar-volman: There is no device with the sysfs path "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host19/target19:0:0/19:0:0:0/block/sdg/sdg1".
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "usb".
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "uas".
thunar-volman: There is no device with the sysfs path "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/block/sdg".
thunar-volman: There is no device with the sysfs path "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/block/sdg/sdg1".
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "uas".
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "usb".
thunar-volman: Unknown block device type "disk".
thunar-volman: Could not detect the volume corresponding to the device.
thunar-volman: Could not detect the volume corresponding to the device.
thunar-volman: Unknown block device type "disk".
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "uas".
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "usb".
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "usb".
thunar-volman: Unknown block device type "disk".
thunar-volman: Could not detect the volume corresponding to the device.
thunar-volman: Could not detect the volume corresponding to the device.
```

Comment: OK, main problem was that the disc did not like the power it was getting from the USB. With a powered USB hub I was able to format and get it running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

First, if the drive is not shown in fdisk, make sure it is getting enough power,if bus powered. Second, do NOT bother to format in Windows 7. Ubuntu 15 cannot properly recognize NTFS or exFAT drives formatted by Windows 7, at least the 1T SSD I have. And those were the only two choices. Instead, format to NTFS in Ubuntu. I used fdisk to create a simple primary partition, and then used mkfs.ntfs to format the drive. The resulting drive will mount on Ubuntu and on Windows 7! Nobody thought to suggest doing it in reverse, I guess because they were thinking that it should work forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write notification specific about ssd cannot mount.

I think you can fix with:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/<device name(this is disk ssd of you)>
```

Comment: Thanks but what is the device name? I can't find it in any of that output.

Comment: You can check device name with "fdisk -l". This is command show all disk of you, you will find disk required

Comment: OK on Windows 7 now, fDisk: /dev/sdc: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x67bd2d2a

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 2000406527 2000404480 953.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: Still will not mount:sudo mount -t hpfs /dev/sdc1 /media/ssd
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.        Works perfectly on Windows 7.

Comment: I reformatted the drive in Windows 7 as exfat. But Ubuntu 15 doesn't work with exfat either. I installed the exfat-fuse and exfat-utils, and I get: sudo mount -t exfat  /dev/sdc1 /media/ssd
FUSE exfat 1.1.0
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.

Comment: sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc1

Disk /dev/sdc1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x67bd2d2a

Device      Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1p1 *     2048 2000406527 2000404480 953.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT